# Java Lambda Method Reference - Clarity Required

Tags: java, generics, lambda, compiler-errors

I am getting error while passing lambda method refrence, with type incompatibilty.
while calling the FUnctional Interface method, code compile perfectly fine and substituting the Concrete objects. While Passing method reference it throwing type incompatibility. Please clear my misunderstanding

```
public interface ParsingFileFunction {
    public <K,T> K getMessage(T inputMessage);
}

public class FileUtility {
    public static Messages readMessage(File kingMesaages){
        //some process here
        return messages; //of Messages type
    }
}
public class SomeController{
    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;
    public void parse(File kingMessage) {
        //compiler error -- The type FileUtility does not define readMessage(T) that is applicable here
        Messages kingdomMessages = someService.getMessage(FileUtility::readMessage,kingMessage);
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeService{
    public Messages getMessage(ParsingFileFunction parse,File file) {
        //this compiles perfectly fine as expected
        return parse.getMessage(file); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can't check the correct types because they are not part of the interface definition but part of the method definition. It works using the following adjustments:

## ParsingFileFunction.java

```
public interface ParsingFileFunction<K, T> {
    K getMessage(T inputMessage);
}
```

Note that the types have been moved to the interface definition.

## SomeService.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;

@Service
public class SomeService {

    public Messages getMessage(ParsingFileFunction<Messages, File> parse, File file) {
        return parse.getMessage(file);
    }
}
```

Note the explicit types in the declaration of `file`.

Comment: This worked, is it mandatory to specifiy Generics at interface level, instead of method level in a FunctionalInterface? Thank you for solution

Comment: Putting the generic types on the method leaves it to the caller of the method to "set" the types but prevents anyone providing the method to do proper type-checks as they depend on, well, the caller of the method.

Comment: It becomes clear when instead of trying to pass a method reference simply pass on a new anonymous class implementing ParsingFileFunction because then you see that the implementation has to provide a method `public <K, T> K getMessage(T inputMessage) {` which has no type parameters and therefore is not satisfied by e. g. `FileUtility::readMessage` that has actual concrete types set.